# Reading Second Value In Line Scala

Tags: scala

I'd like to read line of input of the form `"x y"` from standard input using Scala and assign only `y` to a `var`. Here's what I have so far:

`val Array(_, t) = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)`

This looks pretty ugly though. I tried `val t = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)(1)`, but the compiler complains when I try this. If there's a cleaner solution than using an `Array`, I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution `val Array(_, t) = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)` is ok when string contains valid data.

If you know that second token is valid use this:

```
val t = line.split(" ")(1).toInt
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, why does having the `(1)` after the `map` not work?

Comment: @Impossibility `split` returns `Array`. `(1)` means get element with index 1.

Comment: @Impossibility Scala compiler define your `(1)` as implicit parameter to `map` method.